# How to configure flink-conf.yml for Job Manager?

Tags: installation, apache-flink, cluster-computing

I have a Hadoop Cluster with Yarn designed to run Job Manager on one host and taskmanagers on node managers on 2 different hosts.
Do we need to remove properties related to taskmanager like taskmanager.host from flink-conf.yml from Jobmanager host.

In my opinion, the taskmanager.host and other properties need to be in the flink deployments where taskmanagers are running. Is my understanding correct?
If i am not correct, is there a way to define multiple entries for taskmanagers in job manager host

Set up cluster for flink

Comment: Acoording to Flink docs : "If you use Flink with Yarn or the active Kubernetes integration, the hostnames and ports are automatically discovered". I hope this can help : [Configuring Flink on YARN](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/config/#yarn) and this : [YARN Configuration](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/config/#yarn)

Comment: thank you. I went through this and an additional question is 
where are the configurations like yarn.appmaster.vcores and yarn.containers.vcores go? Do they go in flink-conf.yml? I see these in "YARN" section under Resource Orchestration Frameworks in Flink website. Sorry, I am not able to paste links here for some policy i guess

Comment: All configuration is done in conf/flink-conf.yaml, which is expected to be a flat collection of YAML key value pairs with format key: value.

The configuration is parsed and evaluated when the Flink processes are started. Changes to the configuration file require restarting the relevant processes. [look here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/config/#configuration). Some configurations you can set up programmatically [read this](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/execution/execution_configuration/)

Comment: To insert links use `[link](http://example.com)`. Don't hesitate to click 'Help' to have some hints on how to use mini-Markdown in comments.